# unity How Do I disable current script or any other script in the program within code?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, scripting

say I have 3 scripts called ,BOB,ABE,GUY

In script BOB, I want to enable ABE, and disable GUY... how could this be done in unity, using c#?

Answer (score 1):

First you need to know the gameObject that the script you want to enable/disable is attached to.  For example, if BOB, ABE and GUY are all on the same object, you could say in BOB's code:

```
this.GetComponent<ABE>().enabled = false; //disable ABE
this.GetComponent<GUY>().enabled = true; //enable GUY
```

If the script you are trying to disable is on a different gameObject than you are going to have to get a hold of that object.  See:

[GameObject.Find](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.Find.html?from=index)
[GameObject.FindWithTag](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.FindWithTag.html)

Or perhaps if you are dealing with collisions see:

[OnTriggerEnter](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.OnTriggerEnter.html)
[OnCollisionEnter](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnCollisionEnter.html)

Answer (score 1):

If you have attached all three scripts in same `GameObject` then I would say go with **James Hogle** answer.

If all scripts are not different `GameObjects` then to disable `GUY` in `BOB`you can use the following code in `BOB`

```
GUY guy = FindObjectOfType<GUY>();
guy.enabled = false;
```

similarly you can use it to set `true` or make it `enable`

Comment: Is your GameObject enabled? In which these scripts are attached?

Answer (score 0):

It's better to avoid GameObject.Find in Unity as well as GameObject.GetComponent because of performance (especially if at runtime).

One better solution is to make both ABE and GUY static:

**GUY.cs** :

```
public class GUY : MonoBehaviour {

    public static GUY guy;

    void Awake () {
        guy = this;
    }
}
```

**ABE.cs :**

```
public class ABE : MonoBehaviour {

    public static ABE abe;

    void Awake () {
        abe = this;
    }
}
```

Now, since you the other scripts in this way (static), you can simply do this:

**BOB.cs :**

```
    // Enable ABE
    ABE.abe.enabled = true;
    // Disable GUY
    GUY.guy.enabled = false;
```

---

**Further reading about this topic:**

[Avoid using GameObject.Find](https://akbiggs.silvrback.com/please-stop-using-gameobject-find)

[Slow/Bad Unity function for performance](https://answers.unity.com/questions/452946/which-unity-functions-are-generally-slowbad-for-pe.html#answer-456592)